# how to extract required string using regular expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like this:

"C:\Users\rajkumar2\Desktop\@Bot\UK portal\Version 5.2"

I want output something like this

"C:\Users\rajkumar2\Desktop@Bot\UK portal\Version 5.2"

I am trying this code but didn't get the desired output.

```
Regex.Replace("C:\\Users\\rajkumar2\\Desktop\\@Bot\\UK portal\\Version 5.2","[^\w\.\,!""$%^&*\(\)-_\']","")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the replacement correctly, then a regular non regex replace might work here:

```
Dim input As String = "C:\Users\rajkumar2\Desktop\@Bot\UK portal\Version 5.2"
Dim output As String = input.Replace("\@", "@")
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

This prints:

```
C:\Users\rajkumar2\Desktop@Bot\UK portal\Version 5.2
```